# Saving one image to very many resolutions

Tags: image, automation, scale, photoshop

for a very special case of use i need to resize a large image to very many resolutions, beginning with 1080px height down to 300px height.

So what I need is 1080px, 1079px, 1078px, 1077px, ... in height with proportionally scaling down the image each time (ideally renaming image-1080, image-1079, image-1078, ...).

Of course I could repeat scaling and exporting the image for about 700 times by myself, but thats obviously not what I want to do. However I could not figure out how to automate this task in Adobe Photoshop (or any other program).

Does anybody know a solution how to solve this problem? As the image is scaled down, there should not be a huge quality loss for any of these resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ImageMagick's convert utility:

```
for i in {1080..300}; do convert -resize x$i image.png image-$i.png; done
```

Explanation:

`for` is a bash script loop, the loop variable will be `$i`

`{1080..300}` is a range of numbers, 1080, 1079, ... 301, 300

`convert` is the IM utility that modifies a file and saves with a new name

`-resize xNNN` resizes the image to a new height, changing the width proportionally

so the loop will run this series of commands:

```
convert -resize x1080 image.png image-1080.png
convert -resize x1079 image.png image-1079.png
...
convert -resize x301 image.png image-301.png
convert -resize x300 image.png image-300.png
```

Comment: For everybody using Windows, like me: FOR /L %a in (1080,-1,300) DO convert -resize x%a -quality 60% image-1080.jpg image-%a.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this using imagemagick and a script.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

> As the image is scaled down, there should not be a huge quality loss for any of these resolutions.

Imagemagick is as good as it gets, but the result quality may be affected for some source image content.

Comment: Will try this and mark as correct, if I succeed with this task.